# jquery 1.10.2 conflict with firefox 29.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, firefox, kendo-grid

We have use jquery 1.10.2 http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js)

and firefox version 29.0.1

testing also this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jatinxit/JdrSx/111/)

```
var selected = []; 
$("#button").click(function(){
   var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.tbody.find(".SelectedCB:checked").each(function(){
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var model = grid.dataItem(row);


        selected.push(model);
    });

    console.log(selected);
});
```

but I have not get result of selected array in firebug console so how to solve this conflict with Firefox.

and also works fine in Chrome but not in firefox.

Error: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one

Comment: it's working very fine with me.

Comment: i am using firefox 30, and your fiddle working fine. You may report it to mozilla development community or try to update mozilla.

just an addon you must clear selected [] after click other wise you get similar elements in array on each click

Comment: yes but my mozila firefox 29.0.1 version not working fine and some time working fine other machine firefox browser same version but not woking fine in my browser.

Comment: Are you using Visual studio & added jquery in mvc project via nuget?

Comment: yes i have using VS2012 updated 4 and also added jquery in my mvc project but not working and you can just check to our jsfiddle..

Comment: Added answer hope it helps.

Comment: let me check in our nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio and created MVC project, its adds the jquery using nuget packages automatically.

The error(*I guess it should be warning in firefox rather error*) you get says jquery already has sourceMappingURL & you are adding new one.

*If its warning, don't bother too much about it.*

To resolve :

Use local copy of `jquery.min.js`  already installed by nuget

**OR**

Use local copy of `jquery.min.js` downloaded from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

and remove `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map` from js file.

But if its warning just ignore it. It causes no harm.

Comment: hello pranav it's not warnings it's error and if it's warning then why we not get data in console.log?                             Error: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one

Line 0

Comment: Try using local copy of jquery.min.js & remove `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map` from js file as suggested above.